# How to find description of error in error log?

Tags: mysql, errors, error-log

We have errors like these in our MySQL error log:

`[ERROR] [MY-010211] [Server] Got error 203 when reading table 'xxx'`

But I can't find anything about either MY-010211 nor error 203 in the documentation.

Where can I find more information about this error, or other errors like this in general?

Comment: This is one of the first hits that I got from google: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=85962

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-errors/8.0/en/server-error-reference.html#error_er_reading_table_failed

Comment: @jerichorivera can you post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Errors labelled [MY-XXXXXX] are MySQL 8.0 errors. You can find the definition for this particular error here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-errors/8.0/en/server-error-reference.html#error_er_reading_table_failed.